# C# Interface base usage

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have base Interface:

```
public interface IDebtBase
{
  // with properties
}
```

which is inherited by another interface

```
public interface IDebt : IDebtBase
{
  // with properties
}
```

Another interface defines the IDebt interface in a list:

```
public interface ILoanBase
{
     List<IDebtBase> Debts { get; set; }
}
```

which is inherited for another interface ILoan:

```
public interface ILoan : ILoanBase
{
  // with properties
}
```

The Loan object implements the ILoan:

```
public class Loan : ILoan
{
    List<IDebt> Debts { get; set; }
}
```

For full reference, the Debt object implements IDebt:

```
public class Debt : IDebt
{
     // with properties
}
```

I receive an error that says that List in Loan needs to be IDebtBase not IDebt:

> 'Loan' does not implement interface member 'ILoanBase.Debts'

Should this work, or does Interface inheritance not work this way?

Comment: Use generics and generic constraints

Comment: Where would I put the generic constraint, as an override on the List on ILoan?

Comment: `List<IDebtBase>` and `List<IDebt>` are different types.

Comment: Since IDebt inherits IDebtBase, shouldn't   List<IDebt> Debts  work in the Loan class?

Comment: No it doesn't. Look up covariance and contravariance in C# for some examples. Also please show the concrete `Debt` class the implements `IDebt`.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Loan l = new Loan();
            var a = 1;
        }
    }

    public interface IDebtBase
    {
        // with properties
    }

    public interface IDebt : IDebtBase
    {
        // with properties
    }

    public interface ILoanBase<T> where T : IDebtBase
    {
        List<T> Debts { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ILoan : ILoanBase<IDebt>
    {
        // with properties
    }

    public class Loan : ILoan
    {
        public List<IDebt> Debts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll give a try my concern is that I'm using Entity Framework and I'm going to confuse it.

Comment: Nah it should be able to cope with generics (after all IList is a generics based object.... IList<T>)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is declare a list of interfaces but actually implement a list of concrete types. This is tricky to do with a static language like `C#`. You best choice is to use generics for the loan base interface.

```
public interface IDebtBase
{
    decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public interface IDebt : IDebtBase
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

public interface ILoanBase<TDebt> where TDebt : IDebtBase
{
    List<TDebt> Debts { get; set; }
}

public interface ILoan : ILoanBase<IDebt>
{
    decimal Rate { get; set; }
}

public class Debt : IDebt
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Loan : ILoan
{
    public static decimal DefaultRate=0.18m;
    public Loan()
    {
        this.Debts=new List<IDebt>();
        this.Rate=DefaultRate;
    }
    public List<IDebt> Debts { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public void AddDebt(int id, decimal amount)
    {
        Debts.Add(new Debt() { ID=id, Amount=amount });
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var loan=new Loan() { Rate=0.22m };
        loan.AddDebt(1002, 5400m);
    }
}
```

The drawback is than not all loans derive from one type. That is because `ILoadBase<IDebt>` is different from `ILoadBase<IDebtBase>`. IN my experience building a hierarchy tree with interfaces is very tricky once you start having collections involved.

An alternative to the above is to change the loan type to use the concrete debt class

```
public interface ILoan : ILoanBase<Debt>  // change from ILoanBase<IDebt>
{
    decimal Rate { get; set; }
}


public class Loan : ILoan
{
    public static decimal DefaultRate=0.18m;
    public Loan()
    {
        this.Debts=new List<Debt>();  // change from List<IDebt>
        this.Rate=DefaultRate;
    }
    public List<Debt> Debts { get; set; } // Change from List<IDebt>
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public void AddDebt(int id, decimal amount)
    {
        Debts.Add(new Debt() { ID=id, Amount=amount });
    }
}
```

which will give you in the end a `List<Debt>` collection (which I assume is what you desire). Now to make it more useful create a common base loan class *without generics*

```
public interface ILoanBase
{
    string Issuer { get; set; }
    IList<IDebtBase> GetDebts();
}
```

and use it for every loan interface. Finally in the concrete loan class you need to implement `GetDebts()` which would convert the `List<Debt>` into `List<IDebtBase>`.

```
public interface ILoanBase<TDebt> : ILoanBase
    where TDebt : IDebtBase
{
    List<TDebt> Debts { get; set; }
}
public class Loan : ILoan
{
    ...
    public IList<IDebtBase> GetDebts()
    {
        return Debts.OfType<IDebtBase>().ToList();
    }
}
```

now you have collect all the loans into a single collection

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ILoanBase> loans=new List<ILoanBase>();
        //populate list
        var abc=new Loan() { Issuer="ABC", Rate=0.22m };
        abc.AddDebt(1002, 5400m);
        loans.Add(abc);

        //iterate list
        foreach (var loan in loans)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(loan.Issuer);
            foreach (var debt in loan.GetDebts())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(debt.Amount.ToString("C"));
            }
        }
        // ABC
        // $5,400.00
    }
```

Comment: Interesting approach, you nailed it with " building a hierarchy tree with interfaces is very tricky once you start having collections involved." I'm going to test approach with my app.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain *why* this won't work.

Assume I add another class `Foo : IDebtBase` and I execute

```
myLoan.Debts.Add(New Foo());
```

Adding a `Foo` works on a `List<IDebtBase>` (i.e., it works on `ILoanBase.Debts`), but not on a `List<IDebt>` (i.e., it won't work on `Loan.Debts`).

Thus, if the compiler allowed you to implement `ILoanBase` in `Loan` in the way you proposed, the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) would be violated.

Comment: That makes sense, and thank you for tying it back to Liskov substitution principle.